# how to reset a state in react to null

Tags: reactjs

I used a form that has two drop downs. I have a submit and cancel button. I need to reset my state on clicking cancel button and make the drop down values to initial value which is select. The state is becoming null after two clicks, even after that the select values are not resetting. Can anyone help?

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
     this.state = {
                result:
                    {
                        first: '',
                        second: '',
                        },
                          this.clearValues=this.clearValues.bind(this);
                          }
    clearValues()
    {
        this.setState({ result:
                    {
                        first: '',
                        last: '',
                        }})
                        }
                         render() {
                         return(<div>
                         <div className=" col col-sm-3">
                                        <label>first
                                            <br /><br />

                                            <select className="custom form-group" name="first" value={this.state.result.first} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                                <option>select</option>
                                                {data.map((movie) => {
                                                    return <option key={movie.id}> {movie.first} </option>;
                                                })}
                                            </select>

                                        </label>
                                        <script>console.log(value)</script>
                                    </div>
                                     <div className=" col col-sm-3">
                                        <label>second
                                            <br /><br />

                                            <select className="custom form-group" name="second" value={this.state.result.second} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                                <option>select</option>
                                                {data.map((movie) => {
                                                    return <option key={movie.id}> {movie.second} </option>;
                                                })}
                                            </select>

                                        </label>
                                        <script>console.log(value)</script>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group col col-sm-3">
                                        <button type="submit" value="submit" className="btn  btn-primary" style={styles}    >Search</button></div>
                                      <div className="form-group col col-sm-3">
                                        <button onClick={this.clearValues} type="button" className="btn  btn-default" style={styles} >Clear</button>
                                    </div>
                         </div>);
                         }
```

Comment: your code is not syntactically correct . Can u correct all the compilation errors.

Comment: also, please correct the indentation